# Adding public key to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys still need password

Tags: centos, redhat, centos7

I've misplaced my password for a CentOS VPS I manage. I'm able to use a rescue tool to log in, mount, and `chroot` into the machine. Through this, I have tried to add my public key to `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`. But, when I reboot and try again to log in, it asks for my password.

I suspect there is some SELinux stuff I'm missing.

My question: **Is it possible to inject an SSH public key using `chroot` to access my machine again?**

Comment: `I've misplaced my password ... I am able to ... mount, and chroot into the machine.` - While you are in the chroot, just set your password?  Also, verify your ssh config and make sure you haven't blocked remote access to the root account.

Comment: I tried setting the password using `passwd` but after rebooting it isn't working. Also, at the end of the day, I'd rather use SSH keys than passwords anyway

Comment: `PermitRootLogin yes` is in my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Comment: Sure, but I was betting you had something wrong with permissions or something somewhere, which would be a lot easier to troubleshoot once you had a working connection and could watch your logs.  The other thing I guess I would suggest is to increase the verbosity of your sshd logs from the recovery shell reboot,  attempt to connect, go back to the recovery shell and examine the logs.  There is probably some useful error messages or something that will tell you what is broken.